# Redirecting back after a google script addon

Tags: javascript, scala, google-apps-script, playframework, gmail-addons

I have a Google App Script addon. This addon is initiated by a click on a checkbox. I am trying to figure out the way I can redirect back once the add-on finishes installing.

**view file**

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" required="true" onclick="window.location.assign('/path/to/addonscript/')" id="addon-checkbox">Enable Addon</label>
</div>
```

While the addon script **Code.gs** has some functions related to ad-on working. I am trying to implement a redirect mechanism to `playframework` view page.

A pretty close thing looks like the `onInstall(e)` trigger available [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#oninstall). Any pointers towards solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all lets look at your code:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" required="true" onclick="window.location.assign('/path/to/addonscript/')" id="addon-checkbox">Enable Addon</label>
</div>
```

It seems you want to redirect when the the checkbox is clicked. So, you could do this in two steps:

1. Add an event listener to the checkbox.
2. Send a redirect to the route, if a condition satisfies (such as something is true/false when the installation finishes).

You could have it something like this in your is code:

```
function onInstall(addOnElement) {
  return true; 
} 

document.getElementById("checkBox").addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    var addonElement ="whatever"; //or use docuement.getElementById if you need to get it from the page.
    var isInstalled = onInstall(addonElement); //calling a function that returns true when the installation finishes. 
    if(installed){ //or simply use onInstall() 
      var redirectUrl = "/time/to/redirect"; 
      window.location.replace(redirectUrl); 
    }
}
```

For the above code, you can remove the the `onclick` attribute; and add an `id` (e.g., `id="checkBox"`).

Comment: Dave, what I am actually trying to find out that how do I know when the install addon finishes. A hook or trigger which I can handle with my redirection code.

Comment: @NaumanZafar updated the answer. Maybe along this lines? You know that the function onInstall; just call it when there is a click on the checkbox, and then gets its return value as a value, put it in the if statement and then do what you need to do.